# Is this Matrix Invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $X$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose $m>0$ and let $\operatorname{tr}(X)$ denote the trace of $X$. If $\operatorname {tr}(X^{\top}X)=m$, can i conclude that $X$ is invertible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, take $$X = X^T = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$$
then $$tr(X^TX) = 1\gt 0$$
but $X$ ist not regular.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that $\operatorname{Tr}(X^TX)$ is positive just mean that the matrix is non-zero. so any non-zero matrix which is not invertible will do the job.

Comment: I would say that the sum of the eigenvalues is not $0$, not just that its a non-zero matrix

Comment: What is $Tr(A^TA)$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo what is $A$? just kidding...

Comment: Sorry I meant $X$ (any matrix $n\times n$ with real entries).

Comment: My bad, I thought about the trace of the orifinal matrix for some reason

Answer (score 2):

No, consider 
$X=\pmatrix{
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
}
$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(X^tX)=1$ but $X$ is not invertible.